# Top level object in './docker-compose.yml' needs to be an object not '<class 'NoneType'>'

Tags: django, docker-compose, python-3.8, ubuntu-20.04

I'm using `python` 3.8, `Docker` version 19.03.13, build 4484c46d9d 3.8

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python /code/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
  volumes:
    - .:/code
  ports:
    - 8000:8000
```

Comment: what does your `docker-compose.yml` looks like?

Comment: your `docker-compose.yml` seems to have indent problems. I've edited your question and fix it! use the version I've edited and post the results

Comment: thanks the error was in docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 64):

Maybe **docker-compose.yml** is empty

Comment: In my case it was docker-compose.override.yml that was empty

Comment: Save file and try again

Comment: This was my case. I never saved the file after adding my changes.

Answer (score 20):

Your .yml file must be empty. Try saving the file.

Comment: I feel so embarrassed when this kind of thing happens lol Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

If you have just created your `docker-compose.yml` chances are you haven't saved it and hit `docker-compose up`.

Save it and try again. It should work fine

Answer (score 0):

In case of `docker-compose.dcproj` project check for all the `.yml` files and nothing should be empty.

1. docker-compose.override.yml
2. docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 0):

create file docker-compose.yaml
that looks like the below picture and it started working
[image: docker.compose.yaml]

Answer (score 0):

Hit this because I did

```
docker-compose --file .config/.env.dev up
```

Instead of

```
docker-compose --env-file .config/.env.dev up
```